# Reference Parameter Value in UserData in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have this under parameter section ,

```
Parameters:
  PlatformSelect:
    Description: Cockpit platform Select.
    Type: String
    Default: qa-1
    AllowedValues: [qa-1, qa-2, staging, production]
```

I need to reference this value in my UserData. I’m using Mappings in  between.

```
Mappings:
  bootstrap:
    ubuntu:
      print: echo ${PlatformSelect} >>test.txt

Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref ‘InstanceType’
      KeyName: !Ref ‘KeyName’
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Test
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
          - ‘’
          - - |
              #!/bin/bash
            - Fn::FindInMap:
              - bootstrap
              - ubuntu
              - print
            - |2+
```

This is not working. Not sure the way I refer it is wrong in first place!!

Should I use something before it like,  ‘${AWS::Parameters:PlatformSelect}’ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are using `Mapping` in between?

You could easily use [`!Sub`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) instead

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Test
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            ${PlatformSelect}
```

Comment: No particular reasons! I was being carried away with an existing CF script I had.
This works! Thanks (y)

Answer (score 3):

What about a combination of `Fn::Join` and `Ref`

```
UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
            - ''
            - - '#!/bin/bash\n'
              - 'print: echo'
              - !Ref 'PlatformSelect' 
              - '>>test.txt\n'
```