# Create own cluster structure with AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create my own cluster structure on Amazon Cloudformation. I have 3 servers. 2 server Nginx and other one MySQL server. I create a cluster structure with my own shell script. Is it possible to create with AWS CloudFormation ? How can I get MySQL server IP address then how can I use this IP address in my shell script? (on Nginx servers).

Thanks for your all help.

Comment: Have you tried or written any CFN (CloudFormation) template for that? If yes, why it doesn't work? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CloudFormation template is creating a resource (eg an Amazon EC2 instance), other parts of the template can refer (`!Ref`) to that resource.

While defining the EC2 instances running nginx, you would be providing a **User Data script** that will be executed when the instance starts. Inside the CloudFormation template, where the script is defined, it is possible to `!Ref` another part of the script. CloudFormation will automatically insert that referenced information (such as the database instance's IP address).

For some examples, see:

- [Resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html)
- [Reference Parameter Value in UserData in AWS Cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44776141/174777)
- [Understanding AWS CloudFormation !Sub Syntax](https://www.fischco.org/technica/2017/cloud-formation-sub/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is there any example configuration ? I just can create EC2 instance with the Cloudformation.

Comment: When launching an EC2 instance via CloudFormation, you can specify a script via `UserData`, which will execute when the instance starts. Within the template, you can have CloudFormation insert details of the MySQL server. Alternatively, you could have the stack store the MySQL details in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store, and then retrieve the parameter on the EC2 instance. See: [Integrating AWS CloudFormation with AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Management & Governance Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)